# Pytorch, how to extend a tensor

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to extend a tensor in PyTorch in the following way:

Let `C` be a `3x4` tensor which `requires_grad = True`. I want to have a new `C` which is `3x5` tensor and `C = [C, ones(3,1)]`
(the last column is a one-vector, and others are the old `C`)
Moreover, I need `requires_grad = True` for new `C`.

What is an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this -

```
c = torch.rand((3,4), requires_grad=True)  # a random matrix c of shape 3x4
ones = torch.ones(c.shape[0], 1)  # creating a vector of 1's using shape of c

# merging vector of ones with 'c' along dimension 1 (columns)
c = torch.cat((c, ones), 1)

# c.requires_grad will still return True...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I need to use this tensor as a parameter.

In a first step, I optimize the parameters in `N` epochs.
In the second step, I need to extend the parameters (something I sad before, and your solution works)
In the third step, I should optimize the extended parameters, but parameters are the same as before and not extended.

Comment: Is it possible for you to inform me about the mentioned problem too?

Comment: It's a bit ambiguous what you're trying to achieve here. however, if you could share some code, I think that may help to get to the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot.

I understand the problem. I need to find a way to assign the extended tenser to the parameters of the model.